# how do I get custom field value and if it's none echo identifier_exit? in PHP

Tags: wordpress, plugins, schema

I am trying to write a plugin for schema by using information from my custom_field.So far so good untill I want to do schema for my bundle product.
Example:

```
    $gtin = get_post_meta($post->ID,'gtin',true);?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">

    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id":"<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>",
    "gtin13": "<?php echo $gtin;?>"
```

}

Here is what I did:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
"identifier_exit":"<?php echo $gtin;?>",
"gtin13":"<?php echo $valuegtin;?>";

function mygtin_get_post_meta($gtin){
         $gtin = get_post_meta($post,'gtin',true);
     if (!$gtin = 0){
        return $valuegtin = $gtin;
        elseif return "false"; }
```

}

I want it to echo like this 
"if there is no gtin value echo identifier_exit: false
else echo $gtin"

Answer (score 0):

after I have diging around, I've found this solution:

```
$gtin = get_post_meta($post->ID,'gtin',true);?>
<script type="application/ld+json">

"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"@id":"<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>",
"identifier":"<?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'iden', true );
if ($meta == '') {
    echo 'true';
} 

else {
    echo 'false';
  }
```

?>",